# Problems with a query PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some problems with a Query that I can not get out, the structure of the tables is as follows:

**child**

```
CREATE TABLE CHILD(
child_id SMALLINT,
child_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
birth_date DATE NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(255),
city VARCHAR(255),
CONSTRAINT PK_CHILD PRIMARY KEY(child_id)
```

**letter**

```
CREATE TABLE LETTER(
letter_id SMALLINT,
arrival_date DATE NOT NULL,
number_toys INTEGER NOT NULL,
delivery_mode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
child_id SMALLINT,
CONSTRAINT PK_LETTER PRIMARY KEY(letter_id),
CONSTRAINT CHILD_FK FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES CHILD(child_id)
);
```

**wished_toy**

```
 CREATE TABLE WISHED_TOY(
 letter_id SMALLINT,
 toy_id SMALLINT,
 CONSTRAINT PK_WISHED_TOY PRIMARY KEY(letter_id, toy_id),
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (letter_id) REFERENCES LETTER(letter_id)
 CONSTRAINT LETTER_FK FOREIGN KEY (toy_id) REFERENCES TOY(toy_id)
```

);

**toy**

```
CREATE TABLE TOY(
toy_id SMALLINT,
toy_name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL NOT NULL,
toy_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
manufacturer VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_TOY PRIMARY KEY(toy_id),
);
```

I have to design a query that allows to obtain for each girl born before 2010 the
total number of toys you have ordered. The result must also include
those girls who have not written any letters. Specifically we want the
identifier of the girl, her name and city and the total number of toys ordered
(such as Total_number).

in the gender column of the child table can only be "m" of masculine or "f" of feminine

Do I have to use join?

the part that I have is this

> ```
> select c.child_id,c.child_name,c.city
>   from letter l 
>   join child c
>   on c.child_id=l.child_id
>   where c.gender='m' and c.birth_date between <='2010/01/01';
> ```

Comment: yes! definitely

Comment: yes you'd use join, but be kind to add your table creation commands and some data for all tables, so we can populate and give you an answer -))

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Do you know how to get girls born before 2010? Do you know how to count toys per child? Show us what you have so far.

Comment: @marmeladzeI put the declaration of the tables

Comment: @ThorstenKettnerthe part that I have is this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c.child_id,c.child_name,c.city, coalesce( number_toys,0) counted
  from 
  Child c
  left outer join letter l 
  on c.child_id=l.child_id
  where c.gender='m' and c.birth_date between <='2010/01/01';
```

Or

```
    select c.child_id,c.child_name,c.city, count(wt.letter_id) actualToys
      from 
      Child c
      left outer join letter l 
      on c.child_id=l.child_id
      left outer join wished_toy wt on l.letter_id=wt.letter_id
      where c.gender='m' and c.birth_date between <='2010/01/01'
Group by 
c.child_id,c.child_name,c.city
```

To count the toys referenced by database rows rather than the pre defined count